# Angular / Typescript / Firestore - How to return an observable value within an if statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, scoping

I am using angular and firestore. I'm checking firestore for a value inside my route guard.

I have found that on page refresh, it returns as undefined. However, if I just hardcode a return of true or false, it works.

Any logs within my if statement always return correctly, but doesn't seem to be updating my global variable for some reason.

If I use my site navigation to get back to the root and navigate through my site, it works correctly. However, when I refresh the page, it returns as undefined.

Could it be a scoping issue?

**Route Guard**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';


//testing
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class CheckBillingService implements CanActivate {
    private _subscription: Subscription;
    private userBillingDocRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
    userBilling: Observable<any>;
    public activeAccount:Observable<boolean>

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router,
                private auth: AngularFireAuth,
                private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        this.authService.user.subscribe((user) => {
            if (user) {
                var userId = user.uid;

                this.userBillingDocRef = this.afs.doc('user_billing/${userId}');

                this.userBilling = this.userBillingDocRef.snapshotChanges();
                this.userBilling.subscribe((value) => {

                    const data = value.payload.data();

                    if (data.account_status == "Active") {
                        this.activeAccount = Observable.of(true);
                        console.log('inside if statement for active = ', this.activeAccount);
                    } else {
                        this.activeAccount = Observable.of(false);
                        console.log('inside if statement for not active = ', this.activeAccount);
                        this.router.navigate(['resubscribe']);
                        return Observable.of(false);
                    }

                    console.log('userBilling.subscribe = ', this.activeAccount);
                });

                console.log('just outside userBilling.subscribe = ', this.activeAccount);
            }
        });

        // When refreshig my page, this returns as undefined.
        // If I navigate to the correct page and work my way through the site it works fine
        // However, refresh returns undefined.

        console.log('out of auth = ', this.activeAccount);

        return this.activeAccount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your code the page will run before your observable method is returned as it's running asynchronously, instead return the full method as observable like so

```
 canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

    return Observable.create(observer=> {
this.authService.user.subscribe((user) => {

                if (user) {

                    var userId = user.uid;

                    this.userBillingDocRef = this.afs.doc('user_billing/${userId}');

                    this.userBilling = this.userBillingDocRef.snapshotChanges();
                    this.userBilling.subscribe((value) => {

                        const data = value.payload.data();

                        if (data.account_status == "Active") {
                            this.activeAccount = Observable.of(true);
 // observe here 
        observer.next(true)
                            console.log('inside if statement for active = ', this.activeAccount);
                        } else {
                            this.activeAccount = Observable.of(false);
          // observe here 
        observer.next(false)
                            console.log('inside if statement for not active = ', this.activeAccount);
                            this.router.navigate(['resubscribe']);
                        }

                        console.log('userBilling.subscribe = ', this.activeAccount);
                    });

                    console.log('just outside userBilling.subscribe = ', this.activeAccount);

                }

            });
    });


            // When refreshig my page, this returns as undefined.
            // If I navigate to the correct page and work my way through the site it works fine
            // However, refresh returns undefined.

            console.log('out of auth = ', this.activeAccount);

        }
```

Observe where I wrapped everything in `Observer.create` which you can learn more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44334611/5836034

then `observer.next` will return what you really want the `canActivate` hook to react on

```
  // observe here 
        observer.next(true)
    observer.next(false)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for the quick response. Really good info to know for someone new to this. I'll mark this as the answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the update Theo. It's nice to get a response where someone is providing some real educational value to the question with resources and code. Very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Observables can be **asynchronous**; they're usually used for this purpose. Code outside of subscribe is in such cases executed before one inside subscribe.

That's why it seems like it's "not updating" variables. It is, but you're not accessing them at the correct time. It works when you hardcode the values because then subscribe is executed synchronously.

Comment: Thanks Lazar. I appreciate the response. The above response by Theo is the answer, and matches what you're saying. Thanks again.

Comment: Seeing you're not on SO: no need to personally thank in the comments. Upvote and/or accepting an answer is usually the way to go. Glad you found the solution!